# Is it possible to use a USB camera with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

It is necessary to recognize the motion and record video live.

**Update**
Save enough on your memory card.

***PS***
Maybe I'll repeat the question, but I am not guided in English.
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Arduino is not a powerful processor and can not do much image processing.  I doubt that there is a USB camera that could be connected to the Arduino.

There are a range of OVO cameras that can connect to the Arduino, but I don't think you will be able to record live video on an Arduino with these, where would you store the file for starters?

There is a PIXY camera system, this has its own microprocessor and interfaces with an Arduino.  It can record video and do object recognition.
http://charmedlabs.com/default/pixy-cmucam5/

Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks interesting)) How to get/buy it?

Comment: Found http://charmedlabs.com/default/where-to-order-pixy/